# Jquery Data Tables - Sorts record page wise only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have written the below code to include a jQuery Data table in my system.

```
$("#courseListTable").DataTable({
  "bFilter": false,
  "info": false,
  "paging": false,
  "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
  columnDefs: [
    { orderable: false, targets: -1 },
    { orderable: false, targets: -2 },
  ]
});
```

It sorts record but only those available on the current page. I want it to sort all records.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: How are you loading the data??

Comment: its in ascending order of title.

Comment: I think, @Sougata means, how do you get the data you feed DataTables. The whole dataset or just one page. Update your code with databind and data samples

Comment: Only available on page? Are you using pagination to navigate through data?

Comment: Nope, I am getting whole data set using one query only. This all records in single go to data tables.

Comment: If that is the case you are showing all data in one query then what does this means `It sorts record but only available on page`?

Comment: You need to use server side Pagination and Sorting using DataTable.

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario.

I am fetching 100 records from DB  ascending by title from DB. Adding all 100 records in data tables. 

There is a pagination of 10 records. 

Now when I sort the record on page 1, it only sorts that 10 records. I want to apply that sorting on all 100 records.

Comment: That should work in theory. But in your options you have `paging: false`? Try to build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces your problem so that we can have a closer look.

Comment: Got that, I was using custom Pagination rather then allowing jQuery Data table "Paging" option.
@Raidri :Thanks for useful comments..